# Parallel feature request connection limit

Tags: postgresql, pyqgis

I have a large pool of feature requests that need to be performed on a PostgreSQL layer. Please assume that these requests cannot be joined into larger requests. If I spawn several threads to perform these requests, **there is a limit of 4 database connections to fulfill these requests.** All other threads are blocked waiting for one of these 4 connections to open.

Is there a way to increase this limit? Is this limit imposed by QGIS or by the PostgreSQL server?

Comment: If you look to your postgres.conf file there is a "max_connections" parameter, which is by default 100 at my PostgreSQL 9.4 ... this isn't probably the issue of database

Comment: The "max_connections" is set to 100. There is no limit on any role (rolconnlimit = -1).